# The Grim Reaper, death itself/herself/himself?

Tags: writing, feminine

I want to write a sentence about the Grim Reaper (symbolism for death). I have this sentence -

> The commander winced, almost if he thought Death herself came to collect him and Mary.

Somewhere I heard the sentence

> Cheat death itself

but that just sounds it's about the death and not a reference to the Grim Reaper. In Czech literature, the reaper is portrayed as a woman, and I think in English she is too, but the Grim Reaper sounds masculine.
So which way is it?
Is there and other name to address the reaper that would be feminine?

Comment: Grim, not 'grimm' (are you getting confused with the brothers Grimm?); reference, not refference, English has a capital E. Death herself/itself, not 'dead herself'. The Grim Reaper is conventionally male in Anglo-American culture.

Comment: Sorry for the grammar, so the correct way would be to say
"The commander winced, almost if he thought death himself came to collect him and Mary."
For me it just sounds better with herself, but that might be due to my language having it differently.

Comment: If you are writing original material (e.g. a novel) you can make Death any gender you like.

Comment: A transgender Grim Reaper might be just the spur your novel needs to appeal to a millennial readership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the name Death rather than Dead in English. Death personified as the Grim Reaper is usually assumed to be a male.

If you need a feminine character you could consider Atropos, the third of the three Fates from Greek mythology. It is Atropos who cuts the thread of life, and she is pictured with shears. Atropos is not actually identified with Death though, and Death as the Grim Reaper is pictured with a scythe.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typos.
It sounds weird to me, writing death himself instead of herself, but that might come from my language having feminine designation. I will use death himself thanks to this!

Comment: Don't forget the capital D though, as you are using Death as a name.

Comment: Death as a noun is feminine in French as well (la mort), though I don't know whether they have a Grim Reaper character in their tradition and, if so, whether that character is masculine or feminine. Don't forget that a scythe is traditionally a tool used by a man. There is a Surrealist movie from the early 20th century (possibly 'Le Chien Andalou") where the main character is accompanied by a young woman who is revealed to be "ma mort" or "my death"

Answer (score 1):

> In English and German culture, Death is typically portrayed as male — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(personification))

However, there are plenty of portrayals of Death as a woman, such as both [DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(DC_Comics))'s and [Marvel](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Death_(Earth-616))'s depictions of the character.

In creative writing, you can choose whatever gender for Death personified that you want (but "it" is not used for people or personifications).